# how to get value of an attribute if we are not sure about the position of the attribute in an array in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

Consider the array which I get as response from API call. what if the position of any one of the attributes gets changed and I want to get the attribute salary/id/idProperty i.e., If I am not sure about attribute position how can get its value without hard coding the array with index?

```
var arr = [
                {
                    id: "alex",
                    idProperty: {
                        args: [
                            {
                            name: "alex_name"
                            }, 
                            { 
                            salary: "16L" 
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: "john",
                    idProperty: {
                        args: [
                            {
                            name: "john_name"
                            }, 
                            { 
                            salary: "14L" 
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
         ];
```

Comment: Use `Object.keys` after loop to get the keys.

Comment: A bit of contextualization would be appreciated!
However, let's say the id prop is unique. Then, for example, `arr.find(item => item.id==='john')` will return the object corresponding to john name without taking care of its position in the array

Comment: @Milore thanks for your reply but I dont't want to check if there is a value present in the attribute , I just want value of the attribute . As Pritish Vaidya commented to use Object.keys i really don't know how to use them , I really appreciate if you could that. 

Comment: As @Milore mentioned you can use `arr.find()`. Just pass the returned value to a variable `let found = arr.find(...);` for easy property access. Before moving on you should check if found is not null / undefined.

Comment: Let's say you need salary of john. `const johnSalary = arr.find(item => item.id === 'john').idProperty.args.find(elem => elem.salary).salary`

Comment: @Milore my requirement is I need to get the value of the salary attribute of every object it doesn't matter if the id = alex or john. I don't need the check for Id/user

Comment: I just gave an example of how you can access your array. Your request is not clear at all, so, revise it and try to explain it better. This is simply object manipulation in javascript, which has a lot of functions to treat with it, like map, foreach, filter, find...